# Single Sign On Asp.Net and SharePoint Online Site

Tags: sharepoint-online, asp.net, azure, azure-ad

I'm using a ASP.NET site with links to an SharePoint online site. When we starts ASP.NET application and click on the link to the SharePoint online site , without asking the login screen, we should be redirected to SharePoint online site.

Can you please help us, how to redirect to SharePoint online site without asking the login screen again.

Comment: You must login, it's form based authentication, or you can pass the credintial to the directed site, I am not sure about this point

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by configuring Azure AD authentication for your Asp.NET application.

[Configure Azure AD Authentication for .NET Application](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/aspnet/overview/developing-apps-with-windows-azure/building-real-world-cloud-apps-with-windows-azure/single-sign-on)

[Azure AD Authentication For MVC Web Application](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/azure-ad-authentication-for-mvc-web-application/)

**Note: Make sure you are using the same domain of your SharePoint Online site**

Once the Azure AD Authentication is configured for Asp.NET web application it will be SSO between Asp.NET web application and your SharePoint Online site as both will be sharing the same authentication method.

Comment: will it work for MSA users as well?

Comment: That, I am not sure. I have done it in the past for the normal Azure AD users and it was working fine